# Prove (or disprove) that for a continuous random variable, CDF is continuous.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

We know that CDF, $F_X(x)=P_X((-\infty,x])$ (cumulative distribution function) of a continuous random variable, ie. a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ that follows all the properties that a random variable should, is *right continuous*, and moreover, we have the equation:$$F_X(x_0)-F_X(x_0-)=P_X[\{x_0\}]$$
where $$F_X(x_0-) \equiv \lim_{x\to x_0^{-}} F_X(x)$$

[Proof that CDF is continuous for continuous random variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2947306/1273374) This question is similar, but the answer is not satisfactory, as in, sure, if the $P[\{x\}]$is $0$, then from the above equation its obvious that the cdf is continuous (lhl=rhl). On the other hand, the answerer assumes that the pdf (probability density function), being the derivative of the cdf, exists, and is riemann integrable. This claim is not obvious. I think the author of that answer conflated the definition of continuous random variables with the existence of PDF, instead of the (correct) definition that says its range(X) is continuum.

I would like to know two things:

1. Is there another pathway to somehow show that $P[\{x\}]$ is $0$?
2. Is there more to this "existence of pdf", like, is there a theorem of analysis that allows this?

Comment: With your definition, it's not true: mixture of, say, normal and discrete variables has range $\mathbb R$, but it's CDF isn't continuous. The standard name for random variables that have PDF is absolutely continuous, but some sources omit "absolute". I don't think the property "range is continuum" (what exactly it means? that is has cardinality continuum, or that it is continuum in topological sense?) is an interesting property for random variables.

Comment: @mihaild , yes, I was talking about cardinality being continuum (definition in my book uses "uncountable" cardinality of the range, and I'm only interested in codomain $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually define a random variable as [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Continuous_random_variable) if its cumulative distribution function (CDF) is continuous, so this is simply the definition.

It is true that there are random variables of uncountable range that do not have continuous CDF; we call them mixed random variables.

Comment: According to your definition, and the definition you linked, this answer is correct. but if you scroll up a bit in the selfsame page you linked, I quote "If the image is uncountably infinite (usually an interval) then X is called a continuous random variable."

Comment: (+1) Also, it seems to me that modern probability textbooks are abandoning this potentially confusing terminology and simply using expressions like "random variable with continuous distribution". (I checked several probability textbooks, including Kai Lai Chung, Durrett, Kallenberg, and I could not find an instance of the term "continuous random variable".)

Comment: @SangchulLee, perhaps the probability textbooks you mentioned know better than to confuse their target audience. but e.g the book Hogg, McKean, Craig, few statistics pages from yale university, and colarado university that show up on the very first link on google, call "uncountable ranged random variables" as continuous random variables. even wikipedia in its initial intro paragraph does this, not few paragraphs above mentioning the other, correct definition